# How to find directory containing specific files or directories?

Tags: linux, find

I'm looking for a one-line command that find multiple files or directories contained by a single directory.

```
foo -> bar
    -> baz
    -> quux

temp -> bar
```

I'm looking to only find `foo` because it contains `bar`, `baz`, and `quux`, but not find `temp`.

Due to other reasons, I have to use `tcsh` for this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do what you want and works with the data provided

```
find . -type d -exec test -e '{}'/bar -a -e '{}'/baz -a -e '{}'/quux \;  -print
```

It basically finds directories then checks to see if they contain the relevant files. If they do it prints the name. It works in bash and tcsh.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I the @reese-moore might also be interested in this

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that, expecially if you need to find out this information multiple times, is with `mlocate`. After you install `mlocate`, you have to run `sudo updatedb` to populate index database. Future reindexing is triggered by daily cron job (which is configured by default on many popular Linux distributions).

When you have an up-to-date index, you can run a queries such as:

`locate -r '^/.*/foo/\(bar\|baz\|quux\)$'`

The above command will search everything from the root (`/`) down and print something like:

```
/home/foo/bar
/home/foo/baz
/var/lib/foo/quux
/usr/local/foo/bar
```

Comment: I'm on an AFS mount, so the database option doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to locate your files.
One example: finding a directory named "foo", and listing everything inside:

```
find . -name "foo" -type d | xargs ls -la
```

Another option, if you have `tree`command installed (`sudo apt-get install -y tree`):

```
find . -name "foo" -type d | xargs tree -afi
```

The `-afi`will give you all the files (`-a`), full file path (`-f`) and discard the indentation (`-i`).

Comment: There's probably over 10,000 directories, so I can't do a visual inspection

Answer (score 0):

Try finding all directories and look if they contain your three files/dirs:

```
find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I@@ sh -c '[ -e @@/a ] && [ -e @@/b ] && [ -e @@/c ] && echo @@'
```